# Is it possible to sign EXE (exeutable file) using PositiveSSL Certificate?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, digital-certificate

Is it possible to sign EXE file using PositiveSSL Certificate.
So when trying to open the .exe file, windows will says that the publisher is verified?

Comment: Technically it's possible to do this, however validation will fail, as certificates issued for SSL are not intended to be used for code signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a code signing certificate is required to sign executables (binaries)

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing
- http://www.comodo.com/business-security/code-signing-certificates/code-signing.php